# Execute Stored Procedure using Mysql and Visual?

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, stored-procedures

[image][image]I am developing a visual basic system and using Mysql database engine

Currently I consult from visual basic, but I want to change that for stored procedure, but the problem I have is that calling it from the visual application does not work, they could support me to say that I have a bad code

```
Dim Conexion As New MySqlConnection
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand()
Dim ms As String

Conexion.ConnectionString = "server=65.;database=...;user=..;password=...;"


Conexion.Open()

cmd = New MySqlCommand("Login", Conexion)
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_usuario", usuario)
cmd.Parameters("@_usuario").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_passsword", password)
cmd.Parameters("@_passsword").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_mensaje", MySqlDbType.String)
cmd.Parameters("@_mensaje").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
ms = (cmd.Parameters("@_mensaje").Value)
```

Comment: already attach the error

Comment: what I would like to know or that I would be confirmed if it is so sent to call a stored procedure with parameters from visual basic

Answer (score 0):

You have user privileges problem, before execute a stored procedure some parameters are obtained from `mysql.proc` table and you must have permission to read that table using the current connection.

To fix it, logged as root user, try adding `SELECT` perms to user `depen_depensas`;

```
GRANT SELECT ON mysql.proc TO 'depen_depensas'@'201.162.160.77';
```

Or maybe that user have created with '%' wildcard:

```
GRANT SELECT ON mysql.proc TO 'depen_depensas'@'%';
```

Just use the same user and host when you created the mysql user.

Comment: that code you must execute on your mysql server it is a one-time script.

Comment: I try to run it from the mysql workbench and it marks me the same error, I have to run it from my panel of my phpmyadmin hosting?

Comment: First of all, check the exact user name created, your username have host included or not.. and then choose the grant option adobe.